# Why do emails show multiple times in Windows Live Mail quick views?

Tags: gmail, windows-live-mail

I have around 6 Gmail address all going through my Windows Live Mail, it has 'quick views' which is a great feature and *should* let me view all of my inboxes at once. The problem is, in the quick view, it shows each email a random number of times:

[(Click to enlarge the following image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88hUJ.png)

[image]

It's worth mentioning that none of the emails are in folders/labels, and all of them appear just fine when viewing them through each individual inbox. Does anyone please know how to fix this? The view is unfortunately rather useless for me in it's current state.

(Nope, the emails aren't being sent to multiple accounts by the way)

Comment: On further inspection, it's marked one as 'All mail', one as 'Important', and one as 'Inbox' - nggh! I'm guessing there's no way for WLM to filter this like it does for the inbox view?

Comment: forwarding gmail/any mail to WLM, will/can cause double importing of mail if you have at sometime stopped the forwarding and re-started it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution (of sorts) here - http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/f-9WDGbhGkE

> When in the live mail program as you look at the folders under your
>   email account you will see an inbox on top.  Under the inbox is a
>   folder named Gmail, this folder expands to show "all mail" which is
>   all emails in your box under one folder.   Live mail when showing
>   "unread emails" displays the inbox and the "all mail" folder at the
>   same time.  This creates the duplicates shown in the unread messages
>   tab.   To fix this click on the gmail folder and right click on the
>   "all mail" folder and select Hide this folder.......

Basically hide all of the various folders from Outlook, and the messages will only appear once (for example, hide the 'Important' label, and the 'All mail' label)

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows Live Mail running under Windows 7 on an HP laptop.   I had the same problem- i.e multiple copies of the same messages.  It was like the Sorcerer's Apprentice.  No matter what I did they kept on coming. Until I read in another forum that the virus protection software may be to blame.  I use AVG Free.  I turned off the email scan feature for 24 hours then back on again and the problem was gone.  Hope this helps someone else.